# Long chained exists query with multiple one-to-many mappings in the chain

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

**Edit**: Following piece seems to be the right way:
`session.query(User).join("userGadgets", "gadget", "components","gadgetComponentMetals")`

**Original**:
I have the following tables configured:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Gadget(Base):
    __tablename__ = "gadget"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    brand = Column(String)


class UserGadget(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_gadget"

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    gadget_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('gadget.id'), primary_key=True)

    user = relationship("User", backref=backref('userGadgets', order_by=user_id))
    gadget = relationship("Gadget", backref=backref('userGadgets', order_by=gadget_id))


class GadgetComponent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "gadget_component"

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    gadget_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('gadget.id'))
    component_maker = Column(String)

    host = relationship("Gadget", backref=backref('components', order_by=id))


class ComponentUsingMetal(Base):
    __tablename__ = "component_metal"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    
    component_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('GadgetComponent.id'))  
    metal = Column(String)

    component = relationship("GadgetComponent", backref=backref('gadgetComponentMetals', order_by=id))
```

I want to find all user names for users who own gadgets having at least one component containing some kind of metal. SQL query for this will be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT distinct u.name FROM user u join user_gadget ug on (u.id = ug.user_id) join gadget_component gc on (ug.gadget_id = gc.id) join component_metal cm on (gc.id = cm.component_id) order by u.name
```

I have tried various versions along the line of:          `session.query(User).filter(User.userGadgets.any(UserGadget.gadget.components.any(GadgetComponent.gadgetComponentMetals.exists())))`

I get the below error:
`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with UserGadget.gadget has an attribute 'gadgetComponents'`

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or is there a better way to do this kind of query in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the join() is the better way to go here since any() is going to produce lots of expensive nested subqueries.  but the mistake you made with the "any" is using syntax like:  `UserGadget.gadget.components`.   SQLAlchemy doesn't continue the namespace of attributes in a series like that, e.g. there is no `UserGadget.gadget.components`; there is just `UserGadget.gadget` and `Gadget.components`, separately.  Just like SQL won't let you say, "SELECT * from user_gadget.gadget_id.gadget.component_id" or something, SQLAlchemy needs you to tell it how you want to join together multiple tables that you're querying from.  With the `any()` here it would be something like `any(and_(UserGadget.gadget_id == GadgetComponent.gadget_id))`, but using JOIN is better in any case.